# Merge a GLTF Model with GLTF Animation (Mixamo) into one?

Tags: animation, three.js, gltf

I'm trying to figure out how to add **animations from external files into a GLTF model file, server-side**. Currently, I use threeJS to load the GLTF model into a website and FBXLoader to add animation from external files, which works perfectly. To enable use in Web AR like the Google model-viewer, I would like to merge these into a single GLB or GLTF file via script. I was looking into NodeJS gltf-pipeline or Python pygltflib library which looked promising, but I didn't find a way to include animations.

Does anyone have a solution on how to do this with NodeJS or Python, without an app like i.e. Blender?

Comment: I got the model and animation GLB file export working on the client side. Now I'm modifying everything to work server side, but I'm struggling to import the required threeJS components (GLTFloader, FBXloader and GLTFexporter) in nodeJS. The main threeJS file import works, but not the components. Anyone an idea on how to import these?

Comment: I got it working on the server side with Puppeteer, but the performance isn't great. Can't I just merge these two GLTF (JSON format) files together somehow?